# Rails docker-compose file connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently working on a Dockerized web application using Docker Compose. I have two services defined in my docker-compose.yml file: db and api, where db is a PostgreSQL container and api is a Rails application. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to connect to the PostgreSQL server from my Rails application.

`.env`

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST=127.0.0.1
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"

x-app: &app
  env_file:
    - .env
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true

services:
  db:
    <<: *app
    image: postgres:16.2
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  api:
    <<: *app
    build: .
    command: sh -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - bundle-cache:/usr/local/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  bundle-cache: null
  pg-data: null
  node_modules:
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:3.2.3-alpine
RUN apk update --no-cache && apk add build-base tzdata nodejs libpq-dev postgresql-client --no-cache
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN bundle install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

I updated the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable in my Rails application to `"postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this part:

```
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}"
```

should be inside the `api` service right?

also, the `POSTGRES_HOST` is `db` - the value you used in the `depends_on`.